# SVG arc with conical gradient

Tags: svg, gradient

Is there a way to add a conical gradient like this to an svg path:

[image]

Comment: You can approximate that conical cradient with a number of linear gradients.  See my approximation here: http://jsfiddle.net/Weytu/17/